# Last observation added forward

Tags: r

First question here after some searching and scrolling I'm still stuck

I have a big vector that should always be increasing but it sometimes reset to 0. I'd like that everytime it resets to 0 the previous non-0 value gets added to the following values. I've tried LOCF but it doesn't work as it only fills my 0 values with the previous values and then goes back to the lowest value.

Vector example:

| Data | Desired transformation |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 0 | 6 |
| 0 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |

Comment: @AnilGoyal one number increase from 1 to 2 in the last tow rows will be added to 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will also do ( I haven't removed dummy column `d` for better understanding that what's actually happening here)

```
df %>% mutate(d = c(0, diff(Data)),
              out = cumsum(pmax(-1 *Data, d)))

    Data     d   out
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     0     0
 2     0     0     0
 3     1     1     1
 4     2     1     2
 5     3     1     3
 6     5     2     5
 7     6     1     6
 8     0    -6     6
 9     0     0     6
10     1     1     7
11     2     1     8
```

Once you understand, you can simply do

```
df %>% mutate(out = cumsum(pmax(-1 *Data, c(0, diff(Data)))))

# A tibble: 11 x 2
    Data   out
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     0
 2     0     0
 3     1     1
 4     2     2
 5     3     3
 6     5     5
 7     6     6
 8     0     6
 9     0     6
10     1     7
11     2     8
```

Comment: It's a pity I've never used `pmax` & `pmin` before they seem to be extremely useful.

Comment: Better than mine I was not aware of diff! Upvoted

Comment: Wow! saw this after my previous comment. Really efficient! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can try `cumsum` + `rle` like below

```
v <- df$Data
idx <- with(
  rle(v == 0),
  cumsum(lengths)[values] - 1
)
df$DataOut <- v + cumsum(replace(rep(0, length(v)), idx, v[pmax(1, idx - 1)]))
```

which gives

```
> df
# A tibble: 11 x 2
    Data DataOut
   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     0       0
 2     0       0
 3     1       1
 4     2       2
 5     3       3
 6     5       5
 7     6       6
 8     0       6
 9     0       6
10     1       7
11     2       8
```

Comment: I did not know about `rle`. Always here to teach me something!

Comment: Thank you very much!. I like this although I believe it only works if the length of the "0" rest is 2. So I made a bit of an update but it might be a little heavy. I need to clean it up: `TestVector <- c(0,0,1,2,3,5,0,0,0,2,5,0,0,0,4)`
`idx <- with( rle(TestVector == 0), cumsum(lengths)[values] )`
`idxResetLenghts <- rle(TestVector==0)$lengths[rle(TestVector==0)$values]`
`DataOut <- TestVector + cumsum(replace(rep(0, length(TestVector)), pmax(1, idx - idxResetLenghts + 1), TestVector[pmax(1, idx - idxResetLenghts)])) `

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are much better ways than a `for` loop for your question but I believe this is quite stable and leads to your desired output. I used to be a big fan of `for` loops and whenever I need a solution that requires more flexibility I do not hesitate to use them. In your case this was the first solution that comes to my mind.

```
out <- vector("numeric", length = nrow(df))
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  out[[1]] <- df$Data[[1]]
  out[[i]] <- out[[i-1]] + (df$Data[[i]] - df$Data[[i-1]])
  
  if(df$Data[[i]] == 0 & df$Data[[i-1]] != 0) {
    out[[i]] <- out[[i-1]]
  }
}

cbind(df, out)

   Data out
1     0   0
2     0   0
3     1   1
4     2   2
5     3   3
6     5   5
7     6   6
8     0   6
9     0   6
10    1   7
11    2   8
```

**Data**

```
df <- tibble(
  Data = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 2)
)
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about the for loop, but my data is so big that it would take too long.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using Tidyverse

Setup:

```
library(tidyverse)

(df <- tibble::tibble( Data = c(0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3)))
```

Actual code

```
(
  df
  %>% mutate(to_add = Data - lag(Data),
             to_add = ifelse(is.na(to_add) | to_add < 0, 0, to_add),
             out = cumsum(to_add))
  %>% select( ! to_add)
)
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
    Data   out
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     0
 2     0     0
 3     2     2
 4     4     4
 5     0     4
 6     0     4
 7     1     5
 8     2     6
 9     0     6
10     1     7
11     2     8
```

The trick is to use the `lag` function which returns the value at the previous line.

---

#### Base R (works only if values are consecutive)

```
df <- data.frame( Data = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2))

df$out <- cumsum(df$Data != 0)
```

#### output

```
   Data out
1     0   0
2     0   0
3     1   1
4     2   2
5     0   2
6     0   2
7     1   3
8     2   4
9     0   4
10    1   5
11    2   6
```

---

The trick is to count lines without zeros and then do cumulative sum on it see [cumsum](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cumsum).

`df$Data != 0` will return TRUE if you need to add 1 and will be converted to number 1 when using `cumsum`

Comment: That's nice, but it works only if the sequences are consecutives. For instance, on `c(2,3,5,0,0,2,3,6)` your solution doesn't work. BTW, it looks like that you edited out important parts of your answer (or you meant `cumsum(df$Data != 0)`) .